# Android Contact Phone, Address and Name Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm using a basic Intent to grab a contact in Android Studio. Once a contact is selected, I want to extract address (home), phone and name. I'm currently only able to get name/address or name/phone. I'm not able to get all 3 because of the intent type I believe.

The issue begins in addDeliveryItem() with the intent. Depending on the intent type, I can pull phone number or address. I need both!!!

**Something curious I noticed:** My getContactIDFromURI() returns a different contact ID depending on the intent type.

I have made a big edit to this post in hopes that I can find an answer. I have now included the entire .java file in case you can spot any problems. I'm going crazy and would send some serious love to whoever can figure this one out :(.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //our main super list of deliveries
    ArrayList<String> deliveryListItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    //string adaptor that will handle data of listview
    MyCustomAdapter adapter;

    //clickCount
    int clickCounter = 0;

    //this is required to pick a contact for some reason.
    private static int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize our custom adapter for custom list
        adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(deliveryListItems, this);

        ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /* Begin custom Deliverance functions */
    public void addDeliveryItem(View v){
        //these 3-4 lines create an intent to pick contacts. INTENT TYPE IS DRIVING ME CRAZY
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        //intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }

    //this function handles receiving contact numbers after they have been picked with intent
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //URI to store the contact URI - basically URL to contact
        Uri uriContact;
        String contactName = null;
        String contactPhone = null;
        String contactAddress = null;
        String contactID = null;

        //successful contact lookup like a boss
        if ((requestCode == PICK_CONTACT) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
            //store contact URI
            uriContact = data.getData();

            contactName = getContactNameFromURI(uriContact);
            contactPhone = getContactPhoneFromURI(uriContact);
            contactID = getContactIdFromURI(uriContact);
            contactAddress = getContactAddressFromURI(uriContact);

            //add result to list
            deliveryListItems.add(contactName);
            deliveryListItems.add(contactPhone);
            deliveryListItems.add(contactAddress);
            deliveryListItems.add(contactID);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            clickCounter++;
        }
    }

    public String getContactIdFromURI(Uri uri){
        String contactID = null;

        // getting contacts "ID" that we need for stuff
        Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {
            contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        }
        cursorID.close();

        return contactID;
    }

    public String getContactNameFromURI(Uri uri){
        String contactName = null;
        // querying contact data store
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
            // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.
            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        cursor.close();
        return contactName;
    }

    public String getContactPhoneFromURI(Uri uri){
        String contactNumber = null;
        String contactID = getContactIdFromURI(uri);

        // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                new String[]{contactID},
                null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        cursor.close();
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public String getContactAddressFromURI(Uri uri){
        String rAddress = null;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            try {
                rAddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
            }catch(Exception e){
                return "nope";
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        return rAddress;
    }
}
```

Can I set the intent type to be able to retrieve all the data I need? I obviously don't want to have to select the contact again.

I'm very sorry if this is a simple question. I'm still new with Android development :).

Edit: here are my functions for retrieving contact phone, name and address given URI. They all work with different intent types.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Shaik you can try this to get a Contact ID

```
public static int getContactIDFromNumber(String contactNumber,Context context)
{
    contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
    int phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();
    Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.contactNumber),new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
        while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
            }
        contactLookupCursor.close();

    return phoneContactID;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response but I'm still lost. I'm getting a different contact ID when selecting the same contact with different intent types. This means I can get the phone number fine when using intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE). I can get the address fine when using intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_TYPE). I get different contact IDs when using each type of intent even though I'm picking the same contact. I'm so confused. Why would the contact ID be different for the address vs phone number? Please help!

Comment: Were you running this on an emulator? I believe Contact Ids can change when you use an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Contact name,id,photo,phone you can refer [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/evandrix/7058235). It gives you a clear explanation. For getting the address of the contact you have to modify the code in the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/evandrix/7058235) and add a new function, which is something like given below.

```
// get the contact ID

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
cursor.close();

// get the data package containg the postal information for the contact
cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
    new String[]{ StructuredPostal.STREET,
        StructuredPostal.CITY,
// add more coluns from StructuredPostal if you need them
        StructuredPostal.POSTCODE},
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " +
            StructuredPostal.MIMETYPE + "=?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(id), StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
        null);


Street = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.STREET));
Postcode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
City = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.CITY)));
// etc.
```

This worked for me. You can try it and let me know if you have some troubles.

Comment: Unfortunately that is still giving me an error after cleaning your code above and using the intent in the gist. I cannot access the address unless I am using this as the intent type: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_TYPE

Comment: I noticed that my contact ID is different depending on the intent type I use. This is surely an issue. What is going on? The ID changes from 760 to 6528 on the same contact :(.

Comment: Create an instance of contact id and save it... Then later use it to query your other requirements... If you keep on queuring it may change.... Though i m not sure about it...